# Change text in radio button dynamically in react-native using Hooks

Tags: javascript, react-native

Today i want to create something like form in react native that looks like
[image]

It's pretty simple. i used [this](https://github.com/sramezani/radio-buttons-react-native) lib for radio button. However i want to change this text in the button when i click button next. I used following code.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Button } from "react-native";
import RadioButtonRN from "radio-buttons-react-native";

export default function App() {
  const numRef = useRef(0);
  const questions = [
    {
      question: "What is localhost's IP address?",
      answers: [
        { id: "1", text: "192.168.1.1" },
        { id: "2", text: "127.0.0.1", correct: true },
        { id: "3", text: "209.85.231.104" },
        { id: "4", text: "66.220.149.25" },
      ],
    },
    {
      question: "What kind of11 fruit was used to name a computer in 1984?",
      answers: [
        { id: "1", text: "Blackberry" },
        { id: "2", text: "Blueberry" },
        { id: "3", text: "Pear" },
        { id: "4", text: "Apple", correct: true },
      ],
    },
  ];

  return (
    <View>
      <RadioButtonRN
        data={questions[numRef.current].answers.map((item) => ({
          label: item.text,
          correct: item.correct,
        }))}
        selectedBtn={(e) => {
          console.log(e);
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="Next"
        onPress={() => {
          numRef.current = numRef.current + 1;
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

So right now when i clicked on the next button, the only thing thats updated is variable

> numRef

But  **questions[numRef.current]** doesn't update text in the button.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the value of a ref doesn't result in a re-render. For data that, when it gets changed, should result in a re-render, you should use state instead.

```
export default function App() {
    const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
    // ...

    data={questions[num].answers.map((item) => ({

    // ...

    onPress={() => {
        setNum(num + 1)l
    }}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. So for re-rander data i should use useState instead of useref

Comment: Yes, you should usually be using state by default in React. Refs are less common, and are more for when state just doesn't solve the problem.